# Check if key either not exist or should have a particular value in filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object as

```
var obj = [
    {
      key1: true,
    },
    {
      key1: true,
      key2: true,
    },
    {
      key1: true,
      key2: false,
    }
]
```

And my filter function is

```
const result = obj.filter(item => (!("key2" in item) || item.key2) );
return result;
```

Here I'm trying to filter the array items with either the `key2` should not exist or the `key2` should be true. However, I'm getting the complete items in the result and it is not removing the item with `key2: false`

```js
var obj = [{
    key1: true,
  },
  {
    key1: true,
    key2: true,
  },
  {
    key1: true,
    key2: false,
  }
]


const result = obj.filter(item => (!("key2" in item) || item.key2));
console.log(result);
```

Expected result

```
var obj = [
  {
    key1: true,
  },
  {
    key1: true,
    key2: true,
  },
]
```

Comment: It seems to be working in the snippet. It returns the first two objects. What result are you expecting instead?

Comment: Expected result added with the question. Please check

Comment: Run the snippet, it gets the expected answer.

Comment: @JackBashford I have mentioned this before. From the [`ecmascript-6`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-6/info) wiki *"Only use the `ecmascript-6` tag where the question specifically relates to new features or technical changes provided in ECMAScript 2015."* This is related to filter logic and has nothing to do with ES6. This sort of *badge farming* is not acceptable from users with 20k reps. I mean look at the top users for the last 30 days for [ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-6/topusers) and [object](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/object/topusers)

Comment: I'm also getting the expected result with the exception of the `obj = ` part. Are you expecting this to mutate your original object?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.hasOwnProperty('key2')` to look for the key in the object

```js
var obj = [
    {
      key1: true,
    },
    {
      key1: true,
      key2: true,
    },
    {
      key1: true,
      key2: false,
    }
]

const result = obj.filter(item => (!item.hasOwnProperty('key2') || item.key2) );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Unless there's a `key2` inherited from a prototype, this should return the same thing.

Comment: This also gives the complete result.

Comment: @Hareesh No it doesn't, it just returns the first two objects in the array. Just like your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter on `undefined`:

```js
var data = [ { key1: true, }, { key1: true, key2: true, }, { key1: true, key2: false, } ] 

let result = data.filter(({key2}) => key2 === undefined || key2)

console.log(result)
```

This would filter on key2 being either `truthy` or `undefined`

Or even shorter as suggested by `Aswin`:

```js
var data = [ { key1: true, }, { key1: true, key2: true, }, { key1: true, key2: false, } ] 

let result = data.filter(({key2}) => !key2)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Even smaller `data.filter(({key2}) => !key2)`

Comment: Good catch! Thanks.